# get json data thant convert object into array after that finding particular value from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, recursion

i want to parse country names from the link, i have use the following two methods to parse objects and array to resolve my issue but what i get in response is empty array, kindly help me to resolve issues in this code.

```
   http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json


<?php $result   = []; 
      $result = file_get_contents("http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json"); 
      $result = json_decode($result); 

      function object_to_array($obj) {
         if(is_object($obj)) 
          $obj = (array) $obj;
    if(is_array($obj)) {
         $new = array();
    foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
        $new[$key] = object_to_array($val);
        }
    }

function recursive($needle, $array, $holder = array()) {
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {    
     if (gettype($val) == 'Array') {
        if ($key != $needle) {
            recursive($needle, $val);
        } elseif ($key == $needle) {
            if (!empty($val)) {
                array_push($holder, $val);

               }
            }
        }
    }
    return $holder;
}
        else $new = $obj;
        return $new;
}       


$new_result=array();
$another_result=array();
$new_result = object_to_array($result);

$another_result = recursive('Name',$new_result);
print_r($another_result);
```

looking forward for a quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all country names, you can simply do:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents('http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json');
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$countries = array();

foreach($data['Results'] as $country) {
    $countries[] = $country['Name'];
}

echo $countries[0]; // will output "Bangladesh"
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.